# how can i print a specific valoue from outout Process in Qt 4.8

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

```
QProcess process1;

process1.start("df /local | awk {'print $5'}");
process1.waitForFinished(1000);

QString stdout = process1.readAllStandardOutput();

qDebug()<<stdout;
```

with this code I get the following return

```
"Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/ubi0_1              20184       680     18436   4% /local
```

"
is there any way to get only the value of the Use% field without using regex?

Comment: You could split the string on whitespace into a QStringList and output the 5th column: [https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstring.html#split](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstring.html#split)

Comment: I gave you the native Qt

Comment: is there anything native to Qt that does this? @drescherjm

Comment: `QStringList list = str.split(QRegExp("\\s+"));` could be one way then look at list[4]. Not sure if you count this as using regex. You may want to split by each line first.